# Logging and ignoring exception from Task in scalaz-streams

Tags: scala, scalaz7, scalaz-stream

Let's take an example from some scalaz-stream docs, but with a theoretical twist.

```
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task

val converter: Task[Unit] =
  io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
    .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.txt"))
    .run

// at the end of the universe...
val u: Unit = converter.run
```

In this case the file might very well contain some non-double string, and the `fahrenheitToCelsius` will throw some `NumberFormatException`. Let's say that in this case we want to maybe log this error and ignore it for further stream processing. What's the idiomatic way of doing it? I've seen some examples, but they usually `collectFrom` the stream.

Comment: Probably not so idiomatic for Scalaz, but you can use `Try` for mapping and in case it failed, log the error the way you want (probably this way: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/test/scala/scalaz/stream/examples/WritingAndLogging.scala#L63).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with scalaz.\/ and additional processing steps

```
  def fahrenheitToCelsius(line: String): Throwable \/ String = 
     \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal {
        val fahrenheit = line.toDouble
        val celsius = fahrenheit // replace with real convert
        celsius.toString
     }

  def collectSome[T]: PartialFunction[Option[T], T] = {
    case Some(v) => v
  }

  def logThrowable[T]: PartialFunction[Throwable \/ T, Option[T]] = {
    case -\/(err) => 
      err.printStackTrace()
      None
    case \/-(v) => Some(v)
  }

  val converter: Task[Unit] =
    io.linesR("testdata/fahrenheit.txt")
      .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
      .map(fahrenheitToCelsius)
      .map(logThrowable)
      .collect(collectSome)
      .intersperse("\n")
      .pipe(text.utf8Encode)
      .to(io.fileChunkW("testdata/celsius.txt"))
      .run
```

Comment: Ok, so there's no run/attemptRun executor or a generic handler that can be specified to act on certain Exceptions? Also, I think the `.map(collectCome)` should be a `.collect(collectSome)` in this case.

Comment: by default process will fail on first exception, but a I understand you want to log them all, so you need to catch exceptions on each step that can fail. yeah, it's a typo, is should be collect(collectSome)

Comment: Yes, very handy for IO reads, for which scalaz-streams pretty much are made for, especially if you don't have any control over the data read and the quality of the data. It's a stream - in some cases you just want to throw away the corrupt stuff. But the answer is indeed covering.